# Service Bus Pre Complete Stage

Tags: azureservicebus

Is there a way to place an item in the queue as "Processing" and after a set period of time move to dead letter queue. For example:

- Item gets added to queue
- Item gets picked up by Receiver A
- Receiver A attempts to send email before completing message but system crashes
- Item gets automatically added back to queue
- Item then gets picked up by Receiver B
- Receiver B sends email, but Receiver A sent email, but as crashed unable to complete message

In this scenario, I don't want Receiver A to complete the message before sending the email, just in case for valid reasons it can't and item should be abandoned.

So basically, just before Receiver A sends the email, I want the message to go in a state whereby either Receiver A successfully sends the email and completes the message, Receiver A cant send the email and abandons the message, or where receiver A doesn't act on the message for a set amount of time, the message gets put into dead letter queue

Thanks Dan

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to place an item in the queue as "Processing" and after a set period of time move to dead letter queue.

I would advise not to "leverage" dead-letter queue for anything other than what's intended for. It's responsibility to contain messages that either cannot be processed because they are poisonous or because your system continuously fails to process them do to some logic problems or excessive time it takes.

In your scenario, you want to ensure that no other competing consumer is sending an email duplicate. Assuming email sending doesn't take more than maximum lock duration (5 minutes), the operation should either successfully complete or throw an exception. When you receive the message, you would receive the message in `PeekLock` mode. Completion of the message should be handled by your code *after* email sending is done. Should sending email fail, you'd handle the exception and not handle the incoming message completion.

In case sending takes longer than 5 minutes, you could defer your message. That will suspend message processing. The message won't be delivered to any other competing consumer. In order to retrieve this message, you'd need to access it by the `SequenceNumber` assigned to the originally handled message. This can get tricky, if you process crashes.

Comment: Hi Sean. and thanks for your response. I agree with not using Dead lock after more research. My main question does relate to how would the competing consumer know that the email was sent if the process crashes just after email successfully sent, before it has a chance to complete the message. After more reading, i am inclined to use a DB to track messages with status/extra data. Then first check each consumer does is check this DB to ensure status is free before continuing to process

Comment: Sounds like a case for the Outbox pattern. Think issue with email operation is that it's not a reliable operation. You could send it, but there's no guarantee it will be delivered.

Comment: So each new request, a record is created in DB and the record ID is returned and this is passed into the message for the service bus. The consumer then obtains this record ID, retrieves data from DB and gets the status (im using open/complete/running/error) for now. As long as it says open then i know its either not been processed before, or a previous consumer has tried, but failed and moved status back to open. If process fails just after email, then status will still be in running stage.

Comment: FYI the email is just for example purposes, the consumer could be doing anything. I just want to avoid consumers duplicating work on rare instance consumer crashes before being able to complete the message.

Comment: Yes, you'll be making your handler idempotent.